# How can I serve a static site in a custom URL path in NextJS 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm building a portfolio website that will showcase other websites that I've built (all in NextJS). Each website that will be showcased has its own repository on my GitHub. I will write a bash script that will be executed in the Dockerfile, cloning these predefined repos and building the static files with `npm run build`. This script will create a folder structure with the static files for each website:

```
.
└── static/
    ├── site1
    ├── site2
    └── ...
```

What I need after this is a way to mount each static site to a URL path.

e.g. `myportfolio.com/demo/site1/` serves the files in `/static/site1/` and so on.

How can I do this?

I haven't tried anything.